# how to receive data from the server in a textview or a toast msg

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I am trying to make a socket setup in java. 
And i want to send and receive data from client to server. 
Client is my android Application and server is my PC. 
Client to Server is getting connected and also receiving the data. But when i am trying to send it from the server to client, the android device is not receiving it. I am trying to mention it in a textview or as a Toast.

Thanks in advance

Android Studio 3.1- android version is oreo

Socket Test V 3.0.0

CLIENT:(works fine)

```
public class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
    Socket s;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    PrintWriter pw;


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... voids)
    {
        String message = voids[0];

        try
        {
            s = new Socket( "197.70.107.35", 3344 );
            pw = new PrintWriter( s.getOutputStream() );
            pw.write( message );
            pw.flush();
            //pw.close();
            //s.close();


        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

SERVER PART (Issue)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText e1;
    TextView e2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        e1 = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editText );
        e2 = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.receive );

        Thread myThread =  new Thread( new MyServerThread() );
        myThread.start();

    }

    class MyServerThread implements Runnable {
        Socket s;
        ServerSocket ss;
        InputStreamReader inr;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String message;
        Handler h = new Handler();

        public void run() {
            try {
                char[] data = new char[10];
                ss = new ServerSocket( 3344 );
                while (true) {

                    InputStreamReader inr = new InputStreamReader( s.getInputStream() );
                    int da = inr.read( data, 0, 9 );
                    System.out.print( data );

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void send(View v)
    {
        SendMessage SendMessage= new SendMessage();
        SendMessage.execute( e1.getText().toString());
    }

}
```

Need to receive data from the SERVER to the mobile application(client) as a Toast msg or in a Textview.

Comment: I don't see you are reading message from the serve on the client

Comment: can you please help me how to make this work fine

Comment: You talk about your PC as being the "server", but the code you have shown for the "server" is Android. Also, you aren't calling your `send()` method at all. Either show more code or explain better what you are trying to do.

Comment: i jus want to send and receive data from the client and server. where the server will be my PC and the client will be my android application. I am able connect and send data to the server. But not able to receive from server. @DavidWasser

Comment: It is not clear what is the server. Both Client and Server that you posted are classes of same application, as Server is calling Client's `SendMessage.execute`

Comment: public void run()
{try{ss = new ServerSocket( 3344 );while (true){s = ss.accept();isr = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( isr );
message = bufferedReader.readLine();
h.post( new Runnable()
{@Override public void run()
{Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: You keep saying the same thing over and over. That's no help. Please use other words or draw us a picture or try some other way of communicating. We do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: To check i am using "Socket Test V 3.0.0" application to send and receive the data @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: very simple as that, to my understanding i want to send and receive data through tcp/ip socket. i am using SOCKET TEST 3.0.0 Application as a server @DavidWasser